# From django.core.mail EmailMessage Goes into infinite loop

Tags: python, django

I have a simple ahref link in my Django Project :

```
<a class=" btn btn-md" href="/someurl/{{ some_id }}/">Notify User</a>
```

And on clicking it,the requested URL is :

```
url(r'^someurl/(?P<some_id>\w+)/$', login_required(some_view), name='some_view'),
```

And the requested view is :

```
    def some_view(request,some_id):

            schObj = SomeModel.objects.get(id = some_id) 
            user = schObj.user
            usermail = user.email
            name = user.fname + " " + user.lname

            template = get_template('../templates/email_templates/success_mail.html')
            c = Context({})
            c.update({'some_id':some_id,'address':user.address})       
            c.update({"fullname":name})
            html = template.render(c)
            subject = "Successfull."
            email = EmailMessage(subject, html, to=[usermail],from_email='some_mail@gmail.com')
            email.content_subtype = "html"
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

My Problem is,After clicking the button,email is getting repeatedly sent to the user.And this goes into infinite loop.How to solve this problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redirecting to view itself in this view :

```
def some_view(request,some_id):

        schObj = SomeModel.objects.get(id = some_id) 
        user = schObj.user
        usermail = user.email
        name = user.fname + " " + user.lname
        ....
        ....

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Just change it to something else, other than `request.path`

Comment: Firstly I tried HttpResponseRedirect with a different URL but it yielded the wrong result.Then after redirecting to the previous page,it worked.